# Why write(fileno(stdout)) doesn't working with ent->d_name?

Tags: c, macos

have some problems with printing directory list, using `write()` syscall. I need to print this without using `printf` or `fprintf(stdout)`. Here is my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    char directory[256] = "/Users";
    dir = opendir(directory);

    while (ent=readdir(dir)) {
        write(fileno(stdout), ent->d_name, sizeof(ent->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my output (mac os /Users/ folder):

```
...!("((
.localized"(∞R  Shared∞R €€€(vackdaled..!("((
.localized"(∞R  Shared∞R €€€(vackdaled.localized"(∞R  Shared∞R €€€(vackdaledShared∞R €€€(vackdaledvackdaled
```

But if I use `printf` function, it turns out like this:

```
. 
.. 
.localized 
Shared 
vackdale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the length of the string to the write function, not the size of the buffer.

Try `strlen(ent->d_name)` in stead of `sizeof(ent->d_name)`.